# QStatusBar remove padding

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qstatusbar

I want to add a colored Widget over the full QStatusBar. I added a QLabel with red background-color but there is a padding around the label, which i can't remove.

what i tried:

- setSizeGripEnabled(false)
- setStyleSheet("QStatusBar { border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }"
  "QStatusBar::item { border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }"
- layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

[image: Example in different Colors to differentiate areas]

Update: Example Code:

```
  QWidget *w = new QWidget;
  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  QStatusBar *statusBar = new QStatusBar;
  QLabel *label = new QLabel("Example");

  w->setStyleSheet("background-color: green");

  label->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");

  statusBar->addPermanentWidget(label, 1);
  statusBar->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
  statusBar->setSizeGripEnabled(false);

  setStatusBar(statusBar);

  w->setLayout(layout);
  setCentralWidget(w);
}
```

Comment: Please prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @scopchanov i update the post with an example code

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible without pointer hacking or reimplementing all QStatusBar functionality because `QStatusBar` implementation based on pimpl idiom, which means some implementation hidden in private headers and borders between `QStatusBar` widget and children widgets are hardcoded in [qstatusbar.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/widgets/qstatusbar.cpp#L677)

```
QRect ir = item->w->geometry().adjusted(-2, -1, 2, 1);
...
QStyleOption opt(0);
opt.rect = ir;
...
style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_FrameStatusBarItem, &opt, &p, item->w);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with pointer hacking? Would it be possible to show a solution for this problem? I'm sorry i am new in Qt.

Comment: Pointer hacking is method for accessing private members using pointer arithmetic, it's gennerally a bad idea, and you'll get nasty runtime error if someone changes private headers in qt library. There is another way of achieving your goal: you can remove (hide) status bar completely and instead add QHBoxLayout with labels which acts like statusbar and set it's stretch to 0 (or implement your version of statusbar which is essentialy the same thing)

Comment: that would be awesome without using default qstatusBar. why didn't I think that? Thank you! I upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
QStatusBar{         
        min-height: 20px;
}
```

use the `min-height` css property.